# Parameter name base dependency injection with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject.web.mvc

I have tried finding an answer, may just be bad at searching.  The results I have found did not help so please if you find the answer I am looking for point me in the direction of the force.

I am trying to inject constructor parameters base on name.

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ReportController(IUOW replication)
    {
    }
}
public class NormalController : Controller
{
    public NormalController(IUOW uow)
    {
    }
}
```

So in the ninjectwebcommon file I am trying to inject my controllers with the initialized parameter depending on the parameter name.  This is the binding that works but then all points to the same instance.

```
kernel.Bind<IUOW>().ToConstructor(i => new UOW(new DatabaseContext()));
```

I have tried a lot of answers but keep failing.  Any help or url guidance to my failure in search will be appreciated.  I want to bind the unit of work to a replication database context else to the normal context.  I want to be able to say that the kernel should bind all IUOW in a constructor named replication to new UOW(new ReplicationContext()) otherwise new UOW(new DatabaseContext())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using named bindings? Check out the documentation here:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ReportController([Named("replication")]IUOW replication)
    {
    }
}
public class NormalController : Controller
{
    public NormalController([Named("uow")]IUOW uow)
    {
    }
}
```

You would then bind them this way

```
kernel.Bind<IUOW>().ToConstructor(i => new UOW(new DatabaseContext())).Named("uow");
kernel.Bind<IUOW>().ToConstructor(i => new SomethingElse(new DatabaseContext())).Named("replication");
```

Comment: Thanks a million, tried it but without the name attribute in front of the parameter.  This is working like a charm.