# How to inject two constants implementing the same interface into the same constructor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I've done my research and have found similar questions (like 
[Parameter name base dependency injection with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35417068/3094533)) and the [Contextual Binding wiki page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding), but so far everything I've seen was either based on the target type or on attributes added to the target type (which I would like to avoid).

Is there a way to bind different implementations/constants of the same interface, based on the parameter name in the constructor they need to be injected to?

As an example, Suppose I have these simple classes:

```cs
interface IDoSomething {/* members here */} 
class DoSomething1 : IDoSomething {/* implementation here */}
class DoSomething2 : IDoSomething {/* implementation here */}
```

and a class I want to inject both implementations into:

```cs
class Target
{
    Target(IDoSomething one, IDoSomething two) {/* implementation here */}
    // rest of the code
}
```

Now I know I can use attributes for the parameters:

```cs
class Target
{
    Target([Named("One")] IDoSomething one, [Named("Two")] IDoSomething two) {/* implementation here */}
    // rest of the code
}

// and bind them like this:

Bind<IDoSomething>().To<DoSomething1>().Named("One");
Bind<IDoSomething>().To<DoSomething2>().Named("Two");
```

but is there a way to avoid having these attributes and still inject both implementations into the correct parameters in the same constructor?

Comment: I am always curious about how such designs come about. Yes I under stand this is just an example, but what real world scenario results in such a design being built?

Comment: @Nkosi the target is a class dedicated to listening to a message queue. Now I need to also listen to another queue on a different broker - so I need two different brokers, or add another listener class dedicated to the other broker which basically is repeating the same code as this class. I've temporarily solved this by introducing another class that has both brokers as properties and injecting that instead of the two different brokers, but I don't like this solution very much. I was hoping that Ninject had some better way to do that.

Comment: use `IDoSomething[] multi` instead `IDoSomething one, IDoSomething two`

Comment: @ZoharPeled I see this as a design issue. The description in the last comment appears more interesting than the simplified example provided in the original question. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ZoharPeled if the target class does the same with both dependencies then inject them as a collection as suggested in a previous comment. https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection

Comment: @ZoharPeled you would be able to get a more targeted answer if you [edit] the question with what you are ***actually*** trying to do.

Comment: Well, not exactly repeating the entire code - different brokers have different contexts in the messages I'm listening to, so I would need at least one method different. Perhaps a better design would be to have a base class listening to messages and override the message received handler. However, I still think the answer to this question might be helpful none the less.

Comment: does it *really* make sense to have one listener listening to two different brokers?

Comment: @Josh you're probably correct. As I wrote in a previous comment, it's probably better to have an abstract listener and two different classes implementing it.